# Azure AD B2C Audit API

Tags: azure, audit, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way I can extend the audit logs from Azure Active Directory B2C, like an Api (I know AAD has it own [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-getting-started) for this, but B2C doesn't seem to have one)?

So far, I can only see the audit logs from the Azure Console, and I'd also like to know if it's possible to get any more information such as IP for the user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same API as AAD to get the audit logs for a B2C tenant. Currently the IP is only logged if you use the sign-in policy (not the unified sign-up or sign-in policy). I believe it is in the roadmap to change that in the coming weeks.